# basic sql query problems in hive for using hadoop

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive

Guys I am facing problem with a basic command of SQL.  I am working on hadoop and hive software for learning big data analysis.  I create a table on hadoop file system with name of `cencus`.  I just open hive on terminal and then just performing simple SQL query on it and then saving it on an external excel .csv file

```
hive -e 'select * from cencus' > '/home/training/hackathon/out.csv
```

it works fine and store all the table information into external file

```
hive -e 'select * from sencus where education=children' > /home/training/hackathon/out.csv
```

It’s not working always show exception there is no reduce operator 
I tried lot of time to change the query to:

```
hive -e 'select * from sencus where education=''children'' > /home/training/hackathon/out.csv
hive -e 'select * from sencus where education="children"' > /home/training/hackathon/out.csv
```

But nothing is working please suggest me what I need to do?

Comment: What error do you get? It appears you have different spellings for the table name.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following query could work.

```
hive -e 'select * from sencus where education="children";' > /home/training/hackathon/out.csv
```